# "Input" function for when someone was born

Tags: functions, programming, input

I asked this earlier, but removed my post because I was able to create some more code for it. I am writing a program that asks a user for their birthdate in three separate steps, month, day and year, where the month is given as a word, like "March". I want this program to return the date in the form "mm/dd/yyyy". So a day such as 9 would be written as 09, and I specified that to the user in the Input window..I don't know how to put all this together,to actually get an output of "mm/dd/yyyy".

```
Clear[month, day, year, monthSwitch, blah];
 month = Input["What is your birthday month? Such as " April ""];
 day = Input["What day is your birthday? If the day number falls in between 1-9, please enter 0 number, such as 09 "];
 year = Input["What year were you born in? Please enter the 4 digit year, such as 1994"]

 blah[monthSwitch_] := 
Switch[monthSwitch, "January", "01", "February", "02", "March", 
"03", "April", "04", "May", "05", "June", "06", "July", "07", 
"August", "08", "September", "09", "October", "10", "November", 
"11", "December", "12", _, monthSwitch];
```

I feel like I need nest some of these inputs into an If statement or something, but not too sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
birth := Module[{blah, month, day, year},

  blah[monthSwitch_] := 
   Switch[monthSwitch, "January", "01", "February", "02", "March", 
    "03", "April", "04", "May", "05", "June", "06", "July", "07", 
    "August", "08", "September", "09", "October", "10", "November", 
    "11", "December", "12", _, monthSwitch];
  month = blah @ ToString @ Input["What is your birthday month? Such as " April ""];

  day = StringPadLeft[ToString @ Input["What day is your birthday?"], 2,  "0"];

  year = ToString @ Input["What year were you born in? Please enter the 4 digit year, such as 1994"];

  month <> "/" <> day <> "/" <> year

  ]
```

Usage: just type `birth` in a new cell.

Note that `birth` is a function, so it will not store the date by itself. By typing, e.g.,

```
date = birth
```

the date will be assigned to `date` and you can access it without calling `birth` again.